# Hibernate syntax, writing the FROM as the SELECT DISTINCT FROM?

Tags: hibernate, syntax

I am stuck with the Hibernate syntax.

The syntax I have (and that works) for joining the tables in Hibernate, without creating the models is:

```
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3 WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t1.id=t3.id
```

The code looks like this:

```
...
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerProvider.get();
String qstr = "FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3 WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t1.id=t3.id";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(qstr, Object[].class);
List<Object[]> myTables = query.getResultList();
for(Object[] o:myTables){
    table1 t1 = (table1)o[0];
    table2 t2 = (table2)o[1];
    table3 t3 = (table3)o[2];

    ... do something with the objects here
}
...
```

What I would like to do is to have a statement that looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3 
WHERE t1.id=t2.id 
AND t1.id=t3.id
```

All things I tried give me a syntax error or unwanted repetition.
How should I change the original syntax without a necessity to create models for each join?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no answer since DISTINCT is a feature that might complicate Hibernate that is meant to transfer large amounts of data... It may occur in future releases of Hibernate.  What we can do is either make a Map to check the duplicates against, or to use IS NOT NULL (against the primary keys) in a syntax to avoid the possible full outer joins. Also, try to avoid OR statements and then verify all conditions within the for loop that I have mentioned...

I am looking forward to a better answer, if any.